# Yii2.0 Complete Login Basic Template

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, yii2

i am using yii2 basic template and following this simple tutorial http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/yii-2-user-login-from-database/

in order to create a complete login system with db.
Actually the code doesn't work, because i cannot login, even if everything is ok.
Who can try to reproduce this and see what am i wrong with?

I am using the model views and controller that find below.

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\User;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\Log;

/**
 * UserController implements the CRUD actions for User model.
 */
class UserController extends Controller
{
public function behaviors()
{
   return [

    'verbs' => [
        'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
        'actions' => [
            'logout' => ['post'],
        ],
    ],
];
}

/**
 * Lists all User models.
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionIndex()
{
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => User::find(),
    ]);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}

/**
 * Displays a single User model.
 * @param string $id
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionView($id)
{
    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
    ]);
}

/**
 * Creates a new User model.
 * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new User();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}

/**
 * Updates an existing User model.
 * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
 * @param string $id
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}

/**
 * Deletes an existing User model.
 * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
 * @param string $id
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionDelete($id)
{
    $this->findModel($id)->delete();

    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}

/**
 * Finds the User model based on its primary key value.
 * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
 * @param string $id
 * @return User the loaded model
 * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
 */
protected function findModel($id)
{
    if (($model = User::findOne($id)) !== null) {
        return $model;
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
}
```

User.php

```
   <?php

namespace app\models;
use yii\base\NotSupportedException;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\helpers\Security;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;
use yii\Log;
use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "user".
 *
 * @property string $id
 * @property string $uname
 * @property string $upassw
 * @property string $grade
 * @property string $last_login
 * 
 */
class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
private $id;
private $username;
private $password;
private $authKey;
private $accessToken;



/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'user';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['uname', 'upassw', 'grade', 'last_login'], 'required'],
        [['grade'], 'integer'],
        [['last_login'], 'safe'],
        [['uname'], 'string', 'max' => 25],
        [['upassw'], 'string', 'max' => 255]
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'uname' => 'Uname',
        'upassw' => 'Upassw',
        'grade' => 'Grade',
        'last_login' => 'Last Login',
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function findIdentity($id)
{
    return static::findOne($id);

}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
{
    return static::findOne(['access_token' => $token]);

}

/**
 * Finds user by username
 *
 * @param  string      $username
 * @return static|null
 */
public static function findByUsername($username)
{
      return static::findOne(['uname' => $username]);


}



/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function getAuthKey()
{
    return $this->authKey;
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
{
    return $this->authKey === $authKey;
}

/**
 * Validates password
 *
 * @param  string  $password password to validate
 * @return boolean if password provided is valid for current user
 */
public function validatePassword($password)
{
    Yii::trace("something went wrong".$this->password." and  ".$password);
    return $this->password == sha1($password);

}

/**

 * Generates password hash from password and sets it to the model

 *

 * @param string $password

 */

public function setPassword($password)

{

    $this->password_hash = Security::generatePasswordHash($password);

}



/**

 * Generates "remember me" authentication key

 */

public function generateAuthKey()

{

    $this->auth_key = Security::generateRandomKey();

}


}
```

LoginForm

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\Log;

/**
 * LoginForm is the model behind the login form.
 */
class LoginForm extends Model
{
public $username;
public $password;
public $rememberMe = true;

private $_user = false;


/**
 * @return array the validation rules.
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        // username and password are both required
        [['username', 'password'], 'required'],
        // rememberMe must be a boolean value
        ['rememberMe', 'boolean'],
        // password is validated by validatePassword()
        ['password', 'validatePassword'],
    ];
}

/**
 * Validates the password.
 * This method serves as the inline validation for password.
 *
 * @param string $attribute the attribute currently being validated
 * @param array $params the additional name-value pairs given in the rule
 */
public function validatePassword($attribute, $params)
{
    if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
        $user = $this->getUser();

        if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
            $this->addError($attribute, 'Username o password non valide:user: '.$this->username.'     Pass:'.$this->password." ->Utente".$user->id);
        }


    }
    else Yii::trace("error19");

}

/**
 * Logs in a user using the provided username and password.
 * @return boolean whether the user is logged in successfully
 */
public function login()
{
    if ($this->validate()) {
        return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Finds user by [[username]]
 *
 * @return User|null
 */
public function getUser()
{
    if ($this->_user === false) {
        Yii::trace("username_login_requested".$this->username.var_dump($this->_user));

        $this->_user = User::findByUsername($this->username);

    }

    return $this->_user;
}
}
```

SiteController

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use app\models\LoginForm;
use app\models\ContactForm;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
public function behaviors()
{
    return [

        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'logout' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}

public function actions()
{
    return [
        'error' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
        ],
        'captcha' => [
            'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
            'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
        ],
    ];
}

public function actionIndex()
{
    return $this->render('index');
}

public function actionLogin()
{
    if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    $model = new LoginForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
        return $this->goHome();
    } else {
        return $this->render('login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}

public function actionLogout()
{
    Yii::$app->user->logout();

    return $this->goHome();
}

public function actionContact()
{
    $model = new ContactForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->contact(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])) {
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('contactFormSubmitted');

        return $this->refresh();
    } else {
        return $this->render('contact', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}

public function actionAbout()
{
    return $this->render('about');
}


public function actionStart()
{
    return $this->render('start');
}
}
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;





/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $form yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm */
/* @var $model app\models\LoginForm */

$this->title = 'Login';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="site-login">
    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p>Please fill out the following fields to login:</p>

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id' => 'login-form',
        'options' => ['class' => 'form-horizontal'],
        'fieldConfig' => [
            'template' => "{label}\n<div class=\"col-lg-3\">{input}</div>\n<div class=\"col-lg-8\">{error}</div>",
        'labelOptions' => ['class' => 'col-lg-1 control-label'],
    ],
]); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'username') ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'rememberMe', [
    'template' => "<div class=\"col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-3\">{input}</div>\n<div class=\"col-lg-8\">{error}</div>",
])->checkbox() ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-11">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Login', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'login-button'])         ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
<?php 
var_dump( Yii::$app->user->identity);
echo "<br>";
var_dump($_SESSION);
var_dump(Yii::getVersion());
?>

</div>
```

Thank you all !!

Answer (score 2):

Well one of the reasons might be because you are setting the password like this

```
public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password_hash = Security::generatePasswordHash($password);

}
```

And checking the password like this:

```
public function validatePassword($password)
{
    return $this->password == sha1($password);
```

I believe you are using 2 different algorithms for setting and checking. I have it like this

```
$this->password_hash = Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generatePasswordHash($password);

/**
     * @param string $password password to validate
     * @return bool if password provided is valid for current user
     */
    public function validatePassword($password)
    {
        return Yii::$app->getSecurity()->validatePassword($password, $this->password);
    }
```